# VS2017 C# versus VB creating events

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to get up to speed with C# after years of writing VB code.

I'm trying to add new events in my code. In VB the list of available events is easily accessible but that's not the case in C# and I don't understand  the reason for the difference.

I've looked in several books trying to find an explanation for this to no avail.

Can someone please tell me the reason for the difference and/or is there an easy way to add new events to my C# code?

[image: VB IDE Event List]

[image: C# IDE Event List]

Comment: Double click the form, double click the control (both on the designer surface). Or in code, just start typing the event you want and then tab-tab when you see the right one

Comment: With double click on a control you create its "default" event eventhandler (e.g. click for a button). For other events, click on a control, ->F4 properties -> events and double click on the event you want the handler for

Comment: You can choose an event in design view in the properties window. Choose the control you want and then click the lightning bolt near the top of the window. A list of events for that control will appear. If you double click the event, you will get an event stub with the name you have assigned to the control. You can also assign a procedure from a drop down list if the signature matches.

Comment: In C# event handlers are added in the Form.Designer.cs file. You can see the Add Handler here. In VB the Handles clause attached to the procedure accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Why moving to C# when VB.Net exists ? I'm C++ programmer and I hav programmed in Java but VB is the best ... because it is non case sensitive and this is a very big quality because case sensitive are only use for trick tips that is better to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

> In VB the list of available events is easily accessible but that's not the case in C# and I don't understand the reason for the difference.

Yes, this is a very well known difference between the two languages, which makes working with events much easier in VB than C#.

> Can someone please tell me the reason for the difference and/or is there an easy way to add new events to my C# code?

There is no logical reason except that the two languages are done by two different teams who didn't really communicate much and made different decisions. VB has been always making things as easy as possible and doable in GUI. C# on the other hand, targeted more experienced developers who usually favored typing and shortcuts over using GUI.

If you prefer GUI over typing, the easiest way to do it in C# is to select the form or control, open its properties, switch to the list of events, and then double click on the event that you want. This will automatically switch to the code and insert the event boilerplate for you similar to VB.

For the default events (e.g. `OnClick`), you can simply double click on the form or control in the design mode which will do the above.

Alternatively, switch your Design view to Source view, go to the form or control tag and type the event that you want, it will automatically add `=""` for you. Click between the double-quotes, and select the default event name and it will do the above.